# Can I use a package visible constructor for creation?

Tags: java, object-oriented-design

I need a class where this can be done:

```
// user program
elder_tales.Player p = elder_tales.generate_player();
elder_tales.level_up_player( p );
```

but not:

```
// user program
elder_tales.Player p = new ...whatever
p.set_stats();
p.set_server();
p.calculate_experience()
elder_tales.level_up_player( p )
```

Basically, I want the package to do the instantiating while not allowing the user to do their own instantiating; because instances of type Player are constructed in a complex manner, I decided not to put too much strain on the user to create them with a public constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [Factory Method](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077386/learn-java/factory-methods.html). You just have to make it `static`, so that you can call it on a class, rather than an instantiated object.

```
public static Player generate_player()
{
    elder_tales.Player p = new ...whatever
    p.set_stats();
    p.set_server();
    p.calculate_experience();
    return p;
}
```

This method goes in your `Player` class, or whatever utility class you're using to generate players.  There isn't a way to put bare factory methods or constructor methods outside of a class, as far as I know.

To disable `Player`'s constructor so that only the factory method can use it, omit the constructor's access modifier.  That defaults it to Package Private access.

Answer (score -1):

First, you define the constructor as "package private" by omitting the access modifier. This makes it so that the constructor can be called from same package, but not from package that is using your package.

Then you create a static method that creates and returns the concrete instance. This will have same code as you have written.